# SQL cast date time without hours, Ordering issues also

Tags: sql, casting

```
SELECT 

incident.createDate,
LEFT(incident.createDate,11)as EntryDate,
ContactDetails.cityCode,
patient.insurance,

FROM ......

WHERE 
incident.createDate Between Convert(smalldatetime, '01/07/2012', 103) and Convert(smalldatetime, '31/12/2012', 103) 
and servicecharges.serviceid = 31 
and ServiceRequestDescription LIKE '05.06%'
and chargeDescr = 'Ε0 50.01'
and incident.status != 6
order by createDate ASC, contactdetails.cityCode ASC, patient.insurance ASC
```

As output i get

```
15642     2012-08-03 11:45:07.153       Aug  3 2012         103      15
```

What i want to get is

```
15642     2012-08-03      103        15
```

EntryDate casts date as above so i dont want it. Also ordering is wrong. It orders output correctly with the date but then citycode and insurance are not correct..

Any ideas?

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: ... and **SQL** is only the **Structured Query Language** - and language used by many RDBMS - that alone doesn't tell us what **system** you're using...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
...
CONVERT(Varchar, incident.createDate, 103) as EntryDate,
ContactDetails.cityCode,
patient.insurance,

FROM ......
```

Answer (score 0):

For Sql-Server: I think there is no [**direct format**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to get *`ONLY`* `yyyy-mm-dd`. You could try *`120/121`* and then get the *`left 10 characters`* as below. Little [**demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9812).

```
select left(convert(varchar,incident.createDate,120),10) as EntryDate
```